# Help with Apex test class for a SOQL select method

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

I have an apex class with a method that returns a list of country codes.

```
public class appController {
  public static List<MyApp_Country__c> getCountryData() {
    return [SELECT Id, Name, MyApp_Country_Code__c FROM MyApp_Country__c order by Name];
  }
}
```

The method works fine, but I'm struggling to write the corresponding test class for it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@isTest
private class appController_Test {
  @isTest static void testGetCountryData() {
    List<MyApp_Country__c> countryData = appController.getCountryData();
    System.assert(countryData.isEmpty(), 'it should return all country data');
  }
}
```

Now, my code coverage shows that my method is tested and covered, but I have a feeling I'm missing something since all I'm testing here is if the list is empty or not.

Do I have to create test data even though my method has no parameters? Or should I generate a list of country codes, generate a set of Ids for those codes, then compare that to the result of my method call through an assertion? Or maybe I'm supposed to do something totally different.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you're asking the right questions when it comes to testing. Tests are only as useful as you make them - especially when you start thinking beyond code coverage numbers. Code coverage should not be the only goal, but a byproduct of good test class practices.

With testing, you want to have real-world scenarios. But, of course, there's countless scenarios (ex. 1 record, 2 records, 3 records, etc) so you can't conceivable test everything possible. As such, you'd want to focus on testing boundaries within your code or at least a type of each scenario (positive/negative/null).

In this case, with a query returning records - you may want to assert the following:

- Assert query returns records when it should

  - Assert expected field results in query (`Name`, `MyApp_Country_Code__c`)
  - Assert expected order of results in query (by `Name`)
- Assert query returns no records when it shouldn't

What you're hoping with, for the above, is that your method is doing what you expect it to. If an inadvertent change occurs (ex. someone removes `Name` field in return query), your test would fail as a safeguard.